# How to search on Excel to return multiple fields that match a single value

Tags: excel-formula

I have a table in Excel that has a Data set with multiple values against a single data set.

I need to pull out the data that is against each data set. I have tried using a VLOOKUP however that is only returning the first one in the list. It does not return the others that match the same criteria.

This is my dataset. As can be seen, the vlookup is only returning the first set of data that matches the query. Ideally I need it to return Red, Black and White for the query of John:

[image]

Appreciate it someone can give me some help on this!

Comment: Here's an article that should help answer your question! https://fiveminutelessons.com/learn-microsoft-excel/use-index-lookup-multiple-values-list

Answer (score 0):

Try this - you'll have to fill in the blank cells with the matching names.

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX($A$1:$B$8,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$8=$F$2,ROW($A$1:$A$8)),ROW(1:1)),2)),"",INDEX($A$1:$B$8,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$8=$F$2,ROW($A$1:$A$8)),ROW(1:1)),2))
```

Make sure to auto-fill the rows below and use Ctrl-Shift-Enter when you put in the formula.

Answer (score 0):

There's definitely a more elegant way, but this is what I came up with:

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(ISBLANK(F2),G1=""),"",IF(OR(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("A",MATCH(INDEX(B:B,MATCH($F$2,A:A)+ROW(1:1)-1),B:B)))="",INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("A",MATCH(INDEX(B:B,MATCH($F$2,A:A)+ROW(1:1)-1),B:B)))=$F$2),INDEX(B:B,MATCH($F$2,A:A)+ROW(1:1)-1),"")),"")
```

If you copy it to G2 and drag it down it should work.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are not opposed to generating a working column, or filling in the spaces for the names then the following solution should work for you.

STEP 1

In order for this solution to work there can be no spaces in the name list.  This can be achieved by generating a list with no spaced in another column and working with that information, or you could copy that column and paste value over the first.  I created a working list in this example in Column D.  In D2 I placed the following formula and copied down as required:

```
=IF(A2="",D1,A2)
```

It assumes the list does not start with a blank.

Step 2

Define what you are looking for.  I used E2 to enter the value (name) that was being searched for.  I used the following formula F2 and copied down to get the results.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($D$2:$D$7)/($D$2:$D$7=$E$2),ROW(A1))),"")
```

[image: POC]